# Downloading files from sharepoint/ssrs

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008, internet-explorer-11

In Sharepoint we have a report created by Visual Studio-ssrs.  When the report is executed and the results are shown, when I click on actions/export/excel (or other formats) I receive a message at the bottom of the screen saying that the file ‘couldn’t be downloaded’. The same happens when i try to export a sharepoint list to excel (therefore this is not a problem of ssrs only )What can I do? I have the following additional information for the problem:
- I use IE11 32 bit Excel 2016, SQL/Visual studio 2008.
- I have no problem in downloading any file from Sharepoint (eg from document library) or from internet.
- When I switch user and log in (in the same pc) with another user of the network I do not face the above problem and the file is saved normally
- When I switch user the settings change. I make the settings of my user the same as the settings of the other user (Internet options/security/custom level and internet options/advanced) but there I still have the above problem.
- when I log in with my username to another pc I have no problem.
- I reset IE but I have the same problem.
- I check from manage add-ons and I have the same add-ons as with the add-ons I have when I log in with the other user. The only difference is that in the ‘run without permission category’ the add-on ‘SharePoint OpenDocuments Class’ appears three times compared to two with the no-problem user. All have the same version (15.0.4420.1017)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I run the Internet Explorer as an administrator and the problem was solved.